# Найти ошибку в коде с динамической матрицей

Tags: c

Нужно найти ошибку в коде. Нужно, чтобы она к примеру меняла матрицу -

```
000
000
000
000
000
000
000
000
000
```

на что-то типа такого -

```
111
111
111
000
000
000
000
000
000
```

Причем нужно чтобы матрица была динамической и общее число единиц в ней равнялось n^2, а n - это число вводимое с клавиатуры.

Из-за ошибки по итогу выводится такое -

```
111
110
100
000
000
000
000
000
000
```

Код самой программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n ;
    printf("Vvedite znachenie n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *a;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    a = malloc(4*n*n*n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                for (k = 0; k < n; k++) *(a + i*n + j + k) = 1;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++) *(a + 0*n + j + k) = 1;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++) *(a + i*n + j + k) = 0;
    printf("Izmenenaya matrica\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                printf("%d\t", *(a + i*n + j + k));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените *все* свои

```
 a + i*n + j + k
```

на

```
a + i*n*n + j*n + k
```

У вас же трехмерная матрица, первый индекс выбирает очередные n^2 элементов двумерной матрицы, второй - строку в них, третий - столбец...

https://ideone.com/dQ3dHB